# Limit friendship based on activity points

Tags: socialengine

In Social Engine, is there a way to restrict user sending friend request unless he has activity points?

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no way to restrict to sending the friend request. You need to customize the code for that.

Comment: I did not asked there is limit or not,I have asked way to restrict.

Comment: get the count of friends from engine4_user_membership table and add a check in the menu.